# EmberJS, Helpers and ComputedProperty

Tags: ember.js, helper, computed-properties

I have a *Helper* that receives an array of elements and returns some other array based on the first one.

```
{{#each (sorted-strings myStrings) as |string|}}
  {{string}}
{{/each}}
```

The implementation of the *Helper* can be something like:

```
// app/helpers/sorted-strings.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function sortedStrings(params/*, hash*/) {
  return params[0].sort();
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(sortedStrings);
```

The *Helper* works ok, but if the original `myString` Array changes the changes are not affecting the already rendered list.

How can I combine the behaviour of a *ComputedProperty* and the result of a *Helper*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of struggling I just figured out that the proper solution is to declare a *Component* instead of a *Helper*. This way I can explicitly declare a *Computed Property* that observes changes in the *myStrings* Array:

```
// app/components/sorted-strings.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  myStrings: null,
  sortedMyStrings: Ember.computed('myStrings', function() {
    return this.get('myStrings').sort();
  });
});

// app/templates/components/sorted-strings.hbs
{{#each sortedMyStrings as |string|}}
  {{string}}
{{/each}}

// template
{{sorted-strings myStrings=myStrings}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use  `notifyPropertyChange()` that will notify the helper that the array has changed. I think that the helper has a reference to the array and does not know that it's content or length has changed

Like this

```
actions: {
    add() {
     this.get('myStrings').pushObject('testing');
     this.notifyPropertyChange('myStrings');
    }
  }
```

I have updated the Twiddle - here is the new link https://ember-twiddle.com/31dfcb7b208eb1348f34d90c98f50bbb?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Comment: This works, thanks. But it is insane, what is the point of using all `get` and `set` Ember attributes manipulators if at the end I have to make an explicit notification of a change?. In my case the Array element property is modified by a `{{x-select}}` helper so is difficult to me to invoke the `notifyPropertyChange`.

Comment: I have [here a twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/cf5cf506bf4f10557480f18e824cf700?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) where I am using `ArrayProxy` and all battery of `set` and `get` to try to force Ember to make an implicit notification of a change, but it doesn't work if I comment the explicit notification :/

Answer (score -1):

Passing a computed property to the helper should work fine. Check out this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/537e37c6db0f8cab40d4c3f9a15965f0?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

Maybe your computed property is not getting updated properly.